# Link color not changing

Tags: html, css

Text for link is staying the same color(purple) even though I've never made it that color and want it to be white.

I've tried adding nav:link, nav:active and such but it just changes back to the default with no CSS

```css
nav{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  word-spacing: 300px;
  color: #edf5e1;
  background-color:  #05386b;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <a href="">Projects</a>
  <a href="">About</a>
  <a href="">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

For the text to be all white with no underlines

Comment: `nav a { color: white; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply styling for `nav a` instead of `nav`. `a` have certain styling by default used by the browser.

```css
nav {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  word-spacing: 300px;
  color: yellow;
  background-color: #05386b;
}

nav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <a href="">Projects</a>
  <a href="">About</a>
  <a href="">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

a tags have their own explicit styling, so you need to override them directly. Just setting the color on the parent nav tag won't change them, you need to style the a tags themselves.

```css
nav a{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  word-spacing: 300px;
  color: #edf5e1;
  background-color:  #05386b;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <a href="">Projects</a>
  <a href="">About</a>
  <a href="">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need to target the links directly, like this:

```
nav a,
nav a:link,
nav a:visited,
nav a:hover,
nav a:active {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

You may not need all of the states as shown here, but this will make the link always appear white with no underline.

Answer (score 0):

The actual browser default link color is blue.

For it to appear just replace your CSS selector `nav` with `nav a` to set all the properties on the anchor tag instead of the `nav` element.

```
nav a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  word-spacing: 300px;
  color: #edf5e1;
  background-color:  #05386b;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```